# Django equivalent of PHP's form value array/associative array

Tags: python, django, forms

In PHP, I would do this to get `name` as an array.

```
<input type"text" name="name[]" />
<input type"text" name="name[]" />
```

Or if I wanted to get `name` as an associative array:

```
<input type"text" name="name[first]" />
<input type"text" name="name[last]" />
```

What is the Django equivalent for such things?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

[Check out the QueryDict documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects), particularly the usage of [`QueryDict.getlist(key)`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist).

Since request.POST and request.GET in the view are instances of QueryDict, you could do this:

```
<form action='/my/path/' method='POST'>
<input type='text' name='hi' value='heya1'>
<input type='text' name='hi' value='heya2'>
<input type='submit' value='Go'>
</form>
```

Then something like this:

```
def mypath(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        greetings = request.POST.getlist('hi') # will be ['heya1','heya2']
```

Comment: This fails when key is important. For example name="question[4]" where 4 is question id.

Answer (score 18):

Sorry for digging this up, but Django has an utils.datastructures.DotExpandedDict. Here's a piece of it's docs:

```
>>> d = DotExpandedDict({'person.1.firstname': ['Simon'], \
        'person.1.lastname': ['Willison'], \
        'person.2.firstname': ['Adrian'], \
        'person.2.lastname': ['Holovaty']})
>>> d
{'person': {'1': {'lastname': ['Willison'], 'firstname': ['Simon']}, '2': {'lastname': ['Holovaty'], 'firstname': ['Adrian']}}}
```

The only difference being you use dot's instead of brackets.

EDIT: This mechanism was replaced by form prefixes, but here's the old code you can drop in your app if you still want to use this concept:
https://gist.github.com/grzes/73142ed99dc8ad6ac4fc9fb9f4e87d60

Comment: This is the best solution I have found. Thx.

Comment: I rely on DotExpandedDict in my Django apps, and it is far more useful than QueryDict.getlist. Unfortunately, it has been removed from Django (at least the development version). You can still [grab the source code for it](https://github.com/django/django/commit/c57abd3c29cedcca00821d2a0d5708f10977f3c6#django/utils/datastructures.py), though.

Comment: DotExpandedDict is removed since django 1.5

Comment: Any ideas for a good replacement, since DotExpandedDict is removed?

Comment: yeah, any ideas what to do? team django seems to have done a not so good job here

Comment: @gzy how to actually replace it with form prefixes? I dont get it

Answer (score 5):

Django does not provide a way to get associative arrays (dictionaries in Python) from the request object. As the first answer pointed out, you can use `.getlist()` as needed, or write a function that can take a `QueryDict` and reorganize it to your liking (pulling out key/value pairs if the key matches some `key[*]` pattern, for example).