# Django and HTML arrays

Tags: html, django, arrays, forms

I have a form with this inputs:

```
<input name="person[name]" value="">
<input name="person[surname]" value="">
<input name="person[age]" value="">
```

when I submit, how can i assign that html array to a variable, cause request.POST.getlist('person') doesn't work, i been checking for other post but the only one i found doesn't have anything usefull

[THEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801354/django-equivalent-of-phps-form-value-array-associative-array)

I hope someone could help me figure it out, cause a read the doc, and did quite get the way to do it...

---

the thing is that i have a table in my db with discounts... where every discount has a default value... so i made it

```
discounts = Discount.objects.all( )

{% for i in discounts %} 
<input name="discount[{{ i.id }}]" value="{{ i.default_value }}"> 
{% endfor %}
```

and on my i dont have any method to catch that html array i'm sending... any suggestions?

Comment: Coming form PHP this is a rather intuitive way of operating on forms and arrays. Don't really see a downside of this sort of auto-parsing. Could easily see django allowing request.POST.get('person',{}).get('surname', '')

Comment: For multiple inputs with the identical name you can use request.POST.getlist(...)

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for answering such an old question, but i stuck with the same problem and didn't found any acceptable answers for it. So, here is my solution:

```
def get_post_dict(post, key):
    result = {}
    if post:
        import re
        patt = re.compile('^([a-zA-Z_]\w+)\[([a-zA-Z_\-][\w\-]*)\]$')
        for post_name, value in post.items():
            value = post[post_name]
            match = patt.match(post_name)
            if not match or not value:
                continue
            name = match.group(1)
            if name == key:
                k = match.group(2)
                result.update({k:value})
    return result
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
persons = get_post_dict(request.POST, 'person')
...
```

or

```
django.http.QueryDict.getdict = get_post_dict
persons = request.POST.getdict('person')
```

Comment: Are you sure that Django has not implemented such a useful thing?

Answer (score 1):

this doesn't seem like a very pythonic way to do it. or even a django-nic way to do it.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/

I haven't really done a lot of forms stuff with django yet, but this looks like it would be helpful in terms of automatic generation, validation, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you define your forms this way in templates, you cannot map it to a dictionary directly.

You should obtain individual values only

```
request.POST['person[name]']
```

However, this is no way to use forms in django. You should rather define these fields as per django form declarative syntax ([docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)), and let django handle the rendering in the templates using a tag like:

```
{{form.as_p}}
{{form.as_table}}
```

That way, you can define `save` method on the form class to perform your "array mapping" function. If you want to map it to a model defined, this comes stocked, and your form should extend `ModelForm`, to take that advantage.

Comment: the thing is that i have a table in my db with discounts... where every discount has a default value...

so i made it
{% for i in discounts %}
<input name="discount[{{ i.id }}]" value="{{ i.default_value }}">

and on my view i dont have any method to catch that html array i'm sending... any suggestions?

Comment: You should create a modelform, or a form and pass the initial dictionary to it, as appropriate. docs referred to above can help. If you need help in anything specific, ask a separate question, or update this one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try changing your markup and adding a simple middleware method to transform into a usable data structure for your views.

For instance, given this HTML markup

```
<input name="person:name" value="">
<input name="person:surname" value="">
<input name="person:age" value="">
```

And a middleware function like this..

```
def setup_post_params(get_response):
  def middleware(req):
    if req.method == 'POST':
        req.params = {}
        for key,val in req.POST.dict().items():
            if not ':' in key:
                continue
            k,v = key.split(':')
            if not k in req.params:
                req.params[k] = {}
            req.params[k][v] = val
    return get_response(req)            
return middleware
```

Then you can access in your view funcs w/ `req.params`

```
def my_view_func(req):
    if req.method == 'POST':
      do_something_with(req.params)
```

That looks like this...

```
person: {
  name: "John",
  surname: "Smith",
  age: "20"
}
```