# Does bottle.py work with html associative arrays?

Tags: python, bottle

want to use associative arrays on Bottlypy.  this is what i got on template:

update.tpl

```
<input type="text" name="myvar[myfield1]">
<input type="text" name="myvar[myfield2]">
<input type="text" name="myvar[myfield3]">
```

controller.py

```
def myfun():
    ing = request.forms.getall('myvar')
    print len(ing)
```

which prints out 0

also tested with getlist and didn't work also

is it possible?

Comment: So what are you asking about? Is it "bootley" or "Bottlypy"? Anyway you should add a tag for it.

Comment: Also the are no "arrays" in HTML, it's a markup language.

Comment: @Pavlo try it, but couldn't. ok, let's change it, let's call it "simulate".  the question remains: how?

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do so in Python, whether or not with bottlepy. This approach is mostly likely php-only AFAIK. FYI there's a similar question against django: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801354/django-equivalent-of-phps-form-value-array-associative-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer: no, not possible.

The longer answer: yes, it's possible, but you'll just have to code it yourself.  (N.B., It doesn't seem too hard to me, but I haven't thought it through carefully.)

BTW, there is no such thing as "html associative arrays."  It sounds like you're used to a particular PHP *convention*, but you should keep in mind that that is specific to PHP and has nothing to do with HTML, Python, or Bottle.

Comment: i found a code for your [long answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bottlepy/8m3xTk7IJ2I).  ok, html associative arrays is not on the official docs, but PHP and Ruby use it.