# How to save HTML array inputs

Tags: python, django

I have a form like this:

```
<input name="field[1][title]" type="text">
<input name="field[1][placeholder]" type="text">
<input name="field[1][default]" type="text">

<input name="field[2][title]" type="text">
<input name="field[2][placeholder]" type="text">
<input name="field[2][default]" type="text">
<input name="field[2][max]" value="100" type="number">

<input name="field[3][title]" type="text">
<input name="field[3][placeholder]" type="text">
<input name="field[3][default]" type="text">

<input name="field[4][title]" type="text">
<input name="field[4][placeholder]" type="text">
<input name="field[4][default]" type="text">
<input name="field[4][max]" value="100" type="number">

...
```

How I can save each field as a model row in django?

Something like this:

```
for x in len(field):
    row = Row()
    row.title = field[x][title]
    row.placeholder = field[x][placeholder]
    row.default = field[x][default]
    row.save()
```

## UPDATE

I have index key in form and I don't know how i can use in loop!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django equivalent of PHP's form value array/associative array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801354/django-equivalent-of-phps-form-value-array-associative-array)

Comment: @e4c5 It's not my answer (or I can't understand) I have index value in field name and each field[x] is an array.